# How can I get event of Wi-Fi appearing?

Tags: java, android

I need to make Android application which should send some data into my server every night. If wi-fi connection is absent application should send data when connection become avaiable automatically. Why can I get event about wi-fi availability? Should I use broadcast receiver? Please, give me an example or idea. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Register in your AndroidManifest.xml `BroadcastReceiver` which checks wifi status, like:

```
   <receiver
     android:name=".receivers.WifiStatusReceiver"
     android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver">         
     <intent-filter>             
         <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
         <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />         
     </intent-filter>     
   </receiver>
```

And then implement your own `BroadcastReceiver`, which will handle event when wi-fi will be available, so you can start upload/download

Answer (score 0):

Android comes with a complete support for the WiFi connectivity. The main component is the system-provided WiFiManager. As usual, we obtain it via `getSystemServices()` call to the current context.

Once we have the WiFiManager, we can ask it for the current WIFi connection in form of WiFiInfo object. We can also ask for all the currently available networks via `getConfiguredNetworks()`. That gives us the list of WifiConfigurations.

```
     // Setup WiFi
    wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    // Get WiFi status
    WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
    // info.toString()

    // List available networks
    List<WifiConfiguration> configs = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for (WifiConfiguration config : configs) {
        // config.toString()
    }
```

refer [detailed example](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/40.html)

Comment: I know about it. I don't know how can I get notification about availability wi-fi? For example, now wi-fi isn't available and I want to know when it will be available. Is there anything broadcasts for it?